# Rundeck SSH Execution

Tags: rundeck

We've setup Rundeck community but have some questions regarding SSH execution.

From what I can see it looks like the user who executes the job is configured at the project level and there is no way to change that at a per job per level.

We want to be able to login to Rundeck using our AD credentials (currently working) and run jobs as our individual user id's, is this possible or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use a job level authentication in Rundeck, and it's possible to use the user name as an SSH user (of course the SSH server must be configured with that user to access it).

I made a XML entry node example:

```xml
  <node name="node00" 
        description="Node 00" 
        tags="mytag" 
        hostname="192.168.33.20" 
        osArch="amd64" 
        osFamily="unix" 
        osName="Linux" 
        osVersion="3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64"   
        username="${job.username}" 
        ssh-authentication="password" 
        ssh-password-option="option.sshPassword1"/>
```

If you check carefully, you can see the `username` attribute is set with `${job.username}`, this is a context variable that gets the current username (from, LDAP, AD or `realm.properties` file), you can see all Rundeck context variables [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-workflows.html#context-variables).

This example uses a secure option to pass the password and achieve the SSH authentication, this option is called `sshPassword1` (see the `ssh-password-option` attribute).

Now the [job definition](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#importing-job-definitions) example in YAML format:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: b188c66c-c057-4bb7-98bf-7c84632bc144
  loglevel: INFO
  name: Whoami
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: 'name: node00'
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  options:
  - name: sshPassword1
    secure: true
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: whoami
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: b188c66c-c057-4bb7-98bf-7c84632bc144
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, just to be clear our Rundeck server is in LDAP but the rest of our estate is yet to be added. So what I want to be able to do is execute jobs using the username i have logged into Rundeck as but with a password local to each remote host for that particular username. Is this still possible?

Comment: Sure, the example shows how to pass the passwords using a secure job option. I mean, the node definition gets the user name from the login (AD, LDAP, whatever.) using the `${job.username}` context variable, and the password from the secure option. Of course this means that on remote hosts these users must be defined with their respective passwords to be able to authenticate from Rundeck jobs.

Comment: perfect, I've given this a go but i'm getting failures i'll look into it more tomorrow as it may be container config related. you've given me some great information so thanks for your help!

Comment: So it looks like the keys/user1 password storage path which is set at a project level is being used by default, the option.sshPassword1 within the node declatation xml prompts for a password but this is never used. any thoughts?

Comment: you can set the default value of `option.sshPassword1` option with any password from key storage. In the example, the user must type the password manually but you can use a default value from key storage. Or create a dynamic "keys tree" like keys/${job.username}/password

Comment: We want to avoid using the key storage in order to leverage the option.sshPassword1 option however as I said this isn't getting picked up, the keys/user1 value is being read as soon as the SSH connection is made. If I removed the keys/user1 from the password storage path at a project level the job complains that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Following this https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#ssh-password-with-a-job-option (ans the example) you just need to input the password before the execution. Check your job and make sure that the secure remote option isn't calling the key storage path as a default value, probably that is the reason.

Comment: it worked once I removed any reference to "ssh-password-storage-path" from the project level using the "Edit configuration file" option. thanks for the help!

Comment: Amazing, please remember to mark the answer as correct. Cheers!